# Is there any easy way to convert PHP code for communicating to a MySQL database to code that is for SQL Server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am creating an android app that was previously used with a MySQL database, however now I have to use a SQL Server database. Are there any applications or resources that can convert one to the other?

Here is an example of the php code I was using to connect to the MySQL database:

db_connect.php

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {


    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        //require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        define('__ROOT__',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
        require_once __ROOT__ . '/android_connect/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

create_product.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: That's why you had to use PDO or some other DB abstraction from the start. But in your current situation you can try to simply replace all occurrences of `mysql` with `mssql` in all your scripts. That'll create some errors, but ... should work somehow.

Comment: And move your mysql_* completely out of your scripts to DB_CONNECT class. In your scripts then you'll call `$db->query("SELECT ...");` and in DB_CONNECT class create method `function query($sql){return mysql_query($sql);}`.